# How to find an element in MongoDB that starts and ends with specific letters

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a mongodb database and I need to find elements that start and end with specific letters.
my collection is clients and the field is name.
So basically I want to merge these two commands

```
db.clients.find({name:/s$/})
db.clients.find({name:/^B/})
```

I tried the following syntax but I am trying to find a better way to do it
`db.clients.find({name:/s$/,nom:/^B/})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
 name: {
   "$regex": "^B*.s$"
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dZXxbKdrM7c)

Comment: You can accept my answer if you consider is the expected solution. :)

Comment: `"^B.*.s$"` means starts with "B" and ends with "s", but also have at least one character in between.

Comment: Indeed you are right , the correct regex must be "^B.*s$" . Thanks for noticing!